# How to Convert an Enum to an array of Bytes?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, enums, varbinary

I have an enum as below:

```
[Flags]
public enum AggregationLevel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 00000001
    /// </summary>
    Department = 1,

    /// <summary>
    /// 00000010
    /// </summary>
    Gbu = 2,

    /// <summary>
    /// 00000100
    /// </summary>
    Division = 4,

    /// <summary>
    /// 00001000
    /// </summary>
    Region = 8,

    /// <summary>
    /// 00010000
    /// </summary>
    Market = 16,

    /// <summary>
    /// 00100000
    /// </summary>
    Cluster = 32,

    /// <summary>
    /// 01000000
    /// </summary>
    Store = 64
}
```

Then I have a stored procedure parameter which requires a varbinary (array of bytes).

I have an enum instance which should be passed to it:

```
AggregationLevel thisLevel = AggregationLevel.Department & AggregationLevel.Division;
```

Then, the value should be passed to this stored procedure:

```
var parameter = new SqlParameter("@pBitMask", SqlDbType.VarBinary)
```

parameter = ?

How to convert my 'thisLevel' enum to an array of bytes so that it can be assigned to this sql parameter?

Thanks,

Comment: You need `AggregationLevel thisLevel = AggregationLevel.Department | AggregationLevel.Division;` if you want both Department and Division (note the `|` instead of `&`).

Comment: can you pass an Int to the sql parameter or does it have to be a byte array?

Comment: There's potential for misunderstanding here. Is it possible that you need to have an array of items where each element is a bit of the value in `AggregationLevel`? I.e., you would need an array of 7 items in lieu of that reasoning. However, you may want to rather store the `int` value of the enum in the DB.

Comment: @Kolja, yes Int can be passed to the parameter; thanks.

Comment: @Abel, the value in database is better to be varbinary because I can use & now to compare the values, see this: http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamesrowlandjones/archive/2008/07/04/using-a-bitmask-a-practical-example.aspx

Comment: See under Kieren's question. `varbinary` will cause you a lot of extra work. Unless you have to (i.e., if the db is already designed), you really should have a look at `int` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things..

1) You need to use OR rather than AND:

```
AggregationLevel thisLevel = AggregrationLevel.Department | AggregationLevel.Division;
```

2) You can use this sequence so you don't have to remember powers of 2 in decimal:

```
0x1, 0x2, 0x4, 0x8, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0x100 ...
```

3) Finally, `varbinary` is not what you want.  Look at `integer` or `bigint`.  Enums are stored as `int`s or `long`s, and you are limited to the number of bits in an `int` or a `long`.  If you do want to store in a `varbinary`, you'll need to serialise a value to a string of bytes, will will vary depending on whether you want big-endian, how many bytes should be used for storage - maybe it's even variable, etc.  More information needed.

Two options for #3:

A. If it's just you/code under your control, don't use varbinary, use int or bigint (depending on number of bits required).  Better still (potentially), use bit fields instead, if you're going to query on them

B. If it's not, the DBA or app provider will be able to specify how they want their varbinary populated

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks. in the stored procedure I'd like to do e.g. i & 2 so varbinary is needed but I realized passing integer from c# would work as well. so

Comment: `i & 2` is not limited to `varbinary`. Bitwise operations in SQL is not a problem and will work better, if anything, with integer types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use `int` in your DB and store as `int` value:

```
AggregationLevel thisLevel = AggregationLevel.Department | AggregationLevel.Division;

int val = (int)thisLevel;

AggregationLevel lvlUpd = (AggregationLevel)val;
```

Comment: no I'd like to use varbinary in database to have the bitmasking.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store it as an "array of bytes", a combined value fits comfortably in a single integer.

Comment: the reason for being varbinary is to be able to bitmask it: http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamesrowlandjones/archive/2008/07/04/using-a-bitmask-a-practical-example.aspx

Comment: In SqlServer, you can also bitmask  over plain integers, using the same syntax.